# How to change certain numpy array's target value to another value (if a list of target values is available)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a following array:
`arr = np.arange(24).reshape(4, 6)`

and have a list of target values that should be changed:
`target = [0, 2, 8]`

Now I would like to change all target values in arr to 100.
I could perform that with:

`arr[(arr == 0)|(arr == 2)|(arr == 8)] = 100`

It is not practicable if I have long lists (with 10 elements).
Is there a better way to perform it without using for loop?
Thank you for any inputs :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```py
arr[np.isin(arr, target)] = 100
arr
array([[100,   1, 100,   3,   4,   5],
       [  6,   7, 100,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17],
       [ 18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23]])
```